# Request Tracker sqlite to mysql migration

Tags: mysql, debian-lenny, sqlite, request-tracker

I'm planning to migrate request tracket 3.6 from present server. The rt is running on sqlite and the new one will be mysql. Is there any way to migrate sqlitedb to mysql server.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you ever find a way to do this? I'm trying to do this myself!

Comment: I did not tried, Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671/quick-easy-way-to-migrate-sqlite3-to-mysql

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with request tracker.

In debian there's the package sqlite3-doc. In the file /usr/share/doc/sqlite3-doc/sqlite.html look at the commands .dump and .schema to export the sqlite database tables.

In mysql you can import these SQL files similarly.

If request tracker already created the database and tables, you need not to export the schema.